How to set execution timeout in SSMS
I want to stop all the query that exceeds the given execution timeout value of an instance in SSMS.
I tried to set the execution timeout in SSMS using multiple methods.
Initially, I tried changing the query execution time through the tools option, as described on the website below.
Link
Subsequently, I tried a second method from the link.
In the tools design settings, we can configure values for the execution timeout in seconds.
Link2
However, these methods didn't work even after restarting SSMS.
I have also tried to set the execution timeout under the connection properties in the options tab. Unfortunately, this method also failed.
The below link says that this setting has some issue.
Link3
I want to know how this Execution timeout Setting works. What are the other ways to set this execution timeout in SSMS?
My aim is to stop all the long running queries that I will be executing in my SSMS. This setting must work for all the sessions of my SSMS.

I am trying to stop all the long running queries in my SSMS. I am planning to do this so that my unoptimised queries will not overload the sql server unnecessarily

On SSMS20 this works for me:
Before pressing  'Connect', navigate to 'Connection Properties'.

Here you can change the field 'Execution time-out' to the value in seconds you want to have as a time-out.

After that, connect.
When execution a query which takes longer than the configured period, it will give an error.

Don't forget to change the value back if you don't want it anymore.

The query timeout works just fine for me (SSMS 18). What I did was:
File, New, Database Engine Query.
In that dialog, the Connection Properties Tab: Execution timeout: 10
And then I executed below T-SQL code. After 10 seconds I got an error message from SSMS:
waitfor delay '00:00:15'
print 'hej'



Unfortunately, this method also failed.

Could you describe what you are expected and what is failed?

I want to know how this Execution timeout Setting works

Client establish a connection to server and declare it should be really quick query so if it takes more than executionTimeout (30 seconds) it went sideways so don't waist your time and kill the execution. This let me to change the query.
You cannot overwrite it for OTHER sessions on the server level. In SSMS you can only affect your own session.

I am expecting the query execution timeout to happen for my queries , that is exceeding the time limit set in the above settings
